# Why the loop to search for a string that is present in a file returns True for first iteration and False for the rest?

Tags: python, string, file, search

I have a file named text.txt which contains the following data:

```
My
Name
Is
Lorem
Ipsum
```

My python code:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for i in xrange(5):
        print "Is\n" in f
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
False
False
```

Why the output is True only when i=0?

What to do to get True for all the iterations? I do not want to store the contents of the file anywhere!

Comment: You're not checking the membership in lines but in the file object (an iterable of lines). And the reason of getting that output is that you have `"Is\n"` between your lines and that's why it returns True at the first time but since file objects are iterator like objects once it consumes the file object in first membership checking it returns False for the rest of checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're consuming your file at the first test, so you're at the end of the file for the other iterations.

You could read the contents to a string, but since you don't want to store the file, I propose to `seek` to beginning of the file instead:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for i in range(5):
        f.seek(0)
        print ("Is\n" in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it goes through the file to check. After the first iteration you are at the end of the file. If you want to read file again you can `seek()` to the start of the file.

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for i in xrange(5):
        f.seek(0)
        print "Is\n" in f
```